# Handling exception still cause app crash in flutter

Tags: flutter

I ma handling posible exception with custom exception class and try,catch block,but still app crashes and exception message is not showing.I want to display a toast message when any exception occur.

```
Future<dynamic> GETQuotes(String url, {int skip = 0, int limit = 10}) async {
    dynamic responseData;
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      responseData = reurnJson(response);
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException("No internet connection");
    }
    return responseData;
  }
class QuoteRepo {
  final NetworkApi _networkApi = NetworkApi();
  Future<dynamic> getQuoteAPI(int limit, int skip) async {
    try {
      final data = await _networkApi.GETQuotes(
          "${APPURL.quoteEndPointURL}limit=$limit&skip=$skip");
      return data;
    } on FetchDataException {
      rethrow;
    } on BadRequestException {
      rethrow;
    } on InternalServerError {
      rethrow;
    } on UnAuthorizedRequest {
      rethrow;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
uture<void> getQuote({int limit = 0, int skip = 0}) async {
  
      final data = await _quoteRepo.getQuoteAPI(limit, skip).then((value) {
       
        print(value.toString());
     
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        Utils.showToastMessage(error.toString());
      });
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'app crashes'? What happens? What output in the console do you get?

Comment: app stops functioning

Comment: Does it freeze? Does it go back to your OS home screen? Do you get "Application stopped working" dialog?

Comment: just vs code icon turns to orange and app become irresponsive

Comment: Is it possible that you have "All Exceptions" checked in Run and Debug > Breakpoints and it's not the app crashing but the code execution pauses on breakpoint?

Comment: I debug the code,actually it is peoblem with api not in my code> I works with other apis but does not work and app freeze wuth the api I want to get data from. I want to get data from these apis                                                                                     :class APPURL {
  static String baseURL = 'https://api.quotable.io/';
  String quoteURL = '${baseURL}quotes?limit=10';
  static String quoteBaseURL = "https://dummyjson.com";
  String quoteEndPointURL = "$quoteBaseURL/quotes?";
}